# Nodejs with Sqlite3 and cipher on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have to use sqlite3 (native module) and cipher extension in order to encrypt the database.
Here you can find a tutorial for build the nodejs module from source (https://coolaj86.com/articles/building-sqlcipher-for-node-js-on-raspberry-pi-2/).
But what about under windows? I'm not able to compile and build this node modules under windows (ok under linux).

Comment: can you add links to the sqlite3 and cipher modules?

Comment: See here https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#building-for-sqlcipher